# Multiple Functions Bound to a Single Widget

Tags: events, binding, event-handling, tkinter

I'm binding multiple functions to a single widget using the same sequence (in this case the `'<Button>'` sequence) in Tkinter. To do this I'm using the `add` argument. Is it possible to get all the functions bound to a particular sequence?

snippet :

```
wid.bind('<Button>', func0)
wid.bind('<Button>', func1, add=True)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to be saying you're already doing what you're asking to do. Are you looking for a _better_ way? Or is this way not working? What question are you really asking?

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify. I've already figured out how to bind multiple functions to a particular sequence for a particular widget. I'm wondering if it's possible to get all the functions bound to a sequence of a particular widget. So in the example above, it would be something like `wid.getboundfuncs('<Button>')`, which would return `func0` and `func1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can create one callback function:

```
def cb(event):
    func0()
    func1()
    # ...

wid.bind('<Button>', cb)
```

Also, you can replace `add=True` with `'+'`:

```
wid.bind('<Button>, func1, '+')
```